# UIView are not properly located in ViewController after Rotation

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, orientation

I have a navigation controller with viewcontroller  with container view, where views are loaded programmatically and based on the button click subview is loaded on top of the view. When I add subview from same orientation the views are laid properly but when the subview is rotated while adding on view, the subview is not properly located where they are supposed. How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Use `AutoLayout` or set the frame `didLayoutSubviews` method

Answer (score 0):

you can use auto layout or/and size classes or implement `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` to detect the orientation of device whether it is in landscape or portrait mode and then change the position of your UIView accordingly

Comment: I have implemented auto layout and the landscape view look fine but whenever the view is loaded after orientation the subview break.

Answer (score 0):

You should use of autolayout or size class. Use orientation method than you can set subview possition according them.